# Parsing a 'llll' locale aware formatted data to Postgres default date format using MomentJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, parsing, momentjs

I'm successfully fetching some data using Axios and I need to store this data to my Postgres database.

One of the fields from the fetched data is a `pubDate` field, which is formatted exactly like this:

`"Tue, 15 Apr 2020 20:01:30 +0000"`

Reading through [Moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/), this seems to be this "`locale aware 'llll'`" format.

So, what I need is to parse this pubDate and format it as the default Postgres date format. The pubDate would then look something like this:

```
"2020-04-14T20:01:30"
```

I've been searching for this process for quite some time and just wasn't able to find anything that would work.

I've tried this (did not work), [based on the String + Format from docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
let date = moment(pubDate, 'llll').format();
```

I'm new to NodeJS, sorry if I messed up something. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MomentJS doesn't have a default function for this (I couldn't find anywhere), so I've created one:

```
function parseDate (date) {
// date format: "Thu, 16 Apr 2020 18:29:49 +0000"
   date = String(date);

// date format (after , split): ["", "Day", "Abbreviated Month", "Year", "hour:minute:seconds", "+0000"]. I.E.: ["", "16", "Apr", "2020", "18:29:49", "+0000"]
   let dateInfo = String(date).split(",")[1].split(" ").slice(1, -1);

// ["Day", "Abbreviated Month", "Year", "hour:minute:seconds"]
   let dateString = dateInfo[2] + '-' + moment().month(dateInfo[1]).format("M") + '-' + dateInfo[0] + ' ' + dateInfo[3];

   const parsedDate = moment(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

   return parsedDate;
}
```